# Goroutineが途中で止まってしまう。

Tags: go

Twitterのフォローを自動化するためのコードをGo言語で書いています。下記のようなコードを書きましたが、途中までは正常に動きフォローもしていきますが、しばらくすると途中で止まってしまいます。コード中の`Exceeded Rate Limit.`や`Finished`が出力されていないので意図した箇所で止まってるのではなく異常が起きて止まっている状況です。しかし、どこで処理が止まっているのかがわかりません。あるときは`Add friends`の後であったり、また、ある時は`Waiting`の後であったりします。

**コード**

```
package autofollow

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var (
    accessToken       string
    accessTokenSecret string
)

// AutoFollow is object for following.
type AutoFollow struct {
    words []string
    wn    int
    num   uint
}

// NewAutoFollow is constructor of AutoFollow.
func NewAutoFollow(words []string, n uint) (*AutoFollow, error) {
    if consumerKey := os.Getenv("CONSUMER_KEY"); consumerKey == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("CONSUMER_KEY environvariable was not set")
    } else {
        anaconda.SetConsumerKey(consumerKey)
    }

    if consumerSecret := os.Getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET"); consumerSecret == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("CONSUMER_SECRET environvariable was not set")
    } else {
        anaconda.SetConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
    }

    if accessToken = os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN"); accessToken == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("ACCESS_TOKEN environvariable was not set")
    }

    if accessTokenSecret = os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"); accessTokenSecret == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET environvariable was not set")
    }

    return &AutoFollow{
        words: words,
        wn:    len(words),
        num:   n,
    }, nil
}

// Follow starts following.
func (a *AutoFollow) Follow() (chan *anaconda.User, chan bool, chan error, error) {
    c := make(chan *anaconda.User, a.num)
    fnCh := make(chan bool, 1)
    errCh := make(chan error, a.num)
    go a.roop(c, fnCh, errCh)

    return c, fnCh, errCh, nil
}

func (a *AutoFollow) roop(uc chan *anaconda.User, fnCh chan bool, errCh chan error) {
    fCount := 0
    ec := make(chan error, a.wn)
    nc := make(chan bool, a.wn)
    cn := make(chan bool, a.wn)

    // それぞれの単語ごとにgoroutineを作る
    for _, v := range a.words {
        fmt.Printf("Starting thread for %s\n", v)
        go a.follow(uc, nc, ec, cn, v)
    }

    // 目的の人数に達するまで
L:
    for {
        // 次に進める
        for i := 0; i < a.wn; i++ {
            nc <- true
        }
        select {
        case err := <-ec:
            if err.(anaconda.TwitterError).Code == anaconda.TwitterErrorRateLimitExceeded {
                fmt.Println("Exceeded Rate Limit.")
                // レートリミットに達したら
                time.Sleep(20 * time.Minute)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("error happened %v\n", err)
                errCh <- err
            }
        case <-cn:
            fmt.Println("Add friends")
            fCount++
            if int(a.num) < fCount {
                // 目的の人数に達したら終わる
                fmt.Println("Finished")
                break L
            }
        default:
        }
    }
    fnCh <- true
}

func (a *AutoFollow) follow(uc chan *anaconda.User, nc chan bool, ec chan error, cn chan bool, word string) {
    p := 0
    api := anaconda.NewTwitterApi(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
    for {
        fmt.Println("Waiting")
        <-nc
        v := url.Values{}
        v.Add("page", strconv.Itoa(p))
        v.Add("count", strconv.Itoa(20))
        v.Add("include_entities", "false")
        users, err := api.GetUserSearch(word, v)
        if err != nil {
            // RateLimit
            ec <- err
        } else {
            for _, v := range users {
                if !v.Following && !v.FollowRequestSent && (v.FollowersCount < v.FriendsCount) {
                    // 友だちになる
                    cn <- true
                    user, err := api.FollowUserId(v.Id, url.Values{})
                    if err != nil {
                        ec <- err
                    } else {
                        uc <- &user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        p++
    }
}
```

**出力**

```
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Add friends
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Add friends
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Add friends
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Add friends
Waiting
```

なぜ途中で処理がとまってしまうのでしょうか。わかっていることは下記のとおりです。

- 途中までは正常に動いている
- 出力がでていなくかつ繰り返し実行してもフォローできているのでレートリミットには達していないと考えられる。
- 指定したフォローする人数には達していない。
- エラーも出ていない。

Answer (score -2):

エラーを握りつぶすのをまずやめましょう。

Comment: 具体的にどの行でしょう？パッと見たところでは握りつぶしているようには見えません。

Comment: @NoboNobo 私も握り潰している箇所がわからないので具体的に教えていただけますか。

Comment: すいません。見間違えてました。

Comment: 呼び出し側のコードが見えないと問題点が見えません。動作可能な抜粋をお勧めします。